# Android Material Calendar View how to highlight date range with rounded corner background?

Tags: android, calendarview

Currently I working of prolificinteractive Material Calendar View from github. I able to setBackgroundDrawable of selected the date I wanted. But for now I want to set setBackgroundDrawable of the range of the date as picture below:

[image]

How do I can achieve this kind of rounded corner image background when I got a range of the date. Example From date 18th March 2014 to 22th March 2014.

**Link:**

https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I implemented like this:

[image]

find smaple code here->
https://github.com/Thanvandh/Date-Range-Highlight

**MainActivity.java**

```
final List<String> pinkDateList = Arrays.asList(
        "2019-01-01",
        "2019-01-03", "2019-01-04", "2019-01-05", "2019-01-06");
final List<String> grayDateList = Arrays.asList(
        "2019-01-09", "2019-01-10", "2019-01-11",
        "2019-01-24", "2019-01-25", "2019-01-26", "2019-01-27", "2019-01-28", "2019-01-29");

final String DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";

int pink = 0;
int gray = 1;

MaterialCalendarView calendarView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    calendarView = findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    calendarView.setShowOtherDates(MaterialCalendarView.SHOW_ALL);

    final LocalDate min = getLocalDate("2019-01-01");
    final LocalDate max = getLocalDate("2019-12-30");

    calendarView.state().edit().setMinimumDate(min).setMaximumDate(max).commit();


    setEvent(pinkDateList, pink);
    setEvent(grayDateList, gray);

    calendarView.invalidateDecorators();
}

void setEvent(List<String> dateList, int color) {
    List<LocalDate> localDateList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String string : dateList) {
        LocalDate calendar = getLocalDate(string);
        if (calendar != null) {
            localDateList.add(calendar);
        }
    }


    List<CalendarDay> datesLeft = new ArrayList<>();
    List<CalendarDay> datesCenter = new ArrayList<>();
    List<CalendarDay> datesRight = new ArrayList<>();
    List<CalendarDay> datesIndependent = new ArrayList<>();


    for (LocalDate localDate : localDateList) {

        boolean right = false;
        boolean left = false;

        for (LocalDate day1 : localDateList) {


            if (localDate.isEqual(day1.plusDays(1))) {
                left = true;
            }
            if (day1.isEqual(localDate.plusDays(1))) {
                right = true;
            }
        }

        if (left && right) {
            datesCenter.add(CalendarDay.from(localDate));
        } else if (left) {
            datesLeft.add(CalendarDay.from(localDate));
        } else if (right) {
            datesRight.add(CalendarDay.from(localDate));
        } else {
            datesIndependent.add(CalendarDay.from(localDate));
        }
    }

    if (color == pink) {
        setDecor(datesCenter, R.drawable.p_center);
        setDecor(datesLeft, R.drawable.p_left);
        setDecor(datesRight, R.drawable.p_right);
        setDecor(datesIndependent, R.drawable.p_independent);
    } else {
        setDecor(datesCenter, R.drawable.g_center);
        setDecor(datesLeft, R.drawable.g_left);
        setDecor(datesRight, R.drawable.g_right);
        setDecor(datesIndependent, R.drawable.g_independent);
    }
}

void setDecor(List<CalendarDay> calendarDayList, int drawable) {
    calendarView.addDecorators(new EventDecorator(MainActivity.this
            , drawable
            , calendarDayList));
}

LocalDate getLocalDate(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH);
    try {
        Date input = sdf.parse(date);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(input);
        return LocalDate.of(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1,
                cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        return null;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**EventDecorator.java**

```
public class EventDecorator implements DayViewDecorator {
Context context;
private int drawable;
private HashSet<CalendarDay> dates;

public EventDecorator(Context context, int drawable, List<CalendarDay> calendarDays1) {
    this.context = context;
    this.drawable = drawable;
    this.dates = new HashSet<>(calendarDays1);
}

@Override
public boolean shouldDecorate(CalendarDay day) {
    return dates.contains(day);
}

@Override
public void decorate(DayViewFacade view) {
    // apply drawable to dayView
    view.setSelectionDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(drawable));
    // white text color
    view.addSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.WHITE));
}
}
```

Comment: HI @Thanvandh I used this library but not able to use `onRangeSelected` and `onClickListener`. Can you tell me that both functions really work or not ?

Comment: Both are working well for me.  `cv.setOnRangeSelectedListener(this);`,
`cv.setOnDateChangedListener(this);`